# list out gitlab project with many groups and subgroups

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to list out GitLab projects. We have many groups inside subgroup. Some groups have 800 or more projects. I am able to fetch only half of the projects.

This is the script:

```bash
echo "Project_id, Project_Name, Project_url, Project_default_branch, Group_id" > result_branch.csv
number_of_pages=$(curl -s --head "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/8523968/projects?private_token=$token" | grep -i x-total-pages | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r\n')
for page in $(seq 1 $number_of_pages); do

    curl --silent --header "Private-Token: $token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/8523968/projects?include_subgroups=true&page=$page" | jq -r '.[] | [.id, .name, .web_url, .default_branch, .namespace.id] | @csv' >> result_branch.csv
    cat result_branch.csv | awk {'print$4'} > branches
```

How do I get all projects?

Comment: I have edited your post a little bit so others can better read it. On the first glance without any testing it should be `awk '{ print $4 }` and a `done` is missing at the end. Please check and edit your question if required!

Answer (score 0):

I just played with this locally and got it to work with just a few changes. First, like @Markus mentioned in his comment, you're missing a `done` to terminate the for loop. I'd also move the `cat result_branch.csv` statement outside of the for loop so that only runs once at the end. The loop now looks like this:

```bash
for page in $(seq 1 $number_of_pages); do
    curl --silent --header "Private-Token: $token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/8523968/projects?include_subgroups=true&page=$page" | jq -r '.[] | [.id, .name, .web_url, .default_branch, .namespace.id] | @csv' >> result_branch.csv
done

cat result_branch.csv | awk {'print$4'} > branches
```

The next issue is due to `awk`'s default field separator. In that last step, you're getting strange results since `awk` is using its default field separator instead of what you intend it to do: break on the commas. This is an easy fix with the `-F` flag to set the field separator:

```bash
cat result_branch.csv | awk -F, {'print$4'} > branches
```

All together the script becomes:

```bash
echo "Project_id, Project_Name, Project_url, Project_default_branch, Group_id" > result_branch.csv
number_of_pages=$(curl -s --head "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/8523968/projects?private_token=$token" | grep -i x-total-pages | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r\n')
for page in $(seq 1 $number_of_pages); do
    curl --silent --header "Private-Token: $token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/8523968/projects?include_subgroups=true&page=$page" | jq -r '.[] | [.id, .name, .web_url, .default_branch, .namespace.id] | @csv' >> result_branch.csv
done

cat result_branch.csv | awk -F, '{print $4}'
```

One last thing to note is that your two `awk` statements are written different ways: `awk '{print $2}'` vs. `awk {'print $4'}`. This doesn't seem to make a difference as in my testing I didn't adjust these and it worked just fine, but I always like to do something like this the same way every time, so I'd recommend you use one way or the other and stick with it.

Comment: yeah thanks. but i can able to fetch half of the project list only out 870 project i get only 560 that is the issue

Comment: curl --silent --header "Private-Token: $token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/8523968/projects?include_subgroups=true&page=$page" | jq -r '.[] | [.id, .name, .web_url, .default_branch, .namespace.id, .repo_branches] | @csv' >> result_branch.csv

Comment: It might be your token. You'd either need to be the owner/maintainer of the Group or use a token that was created with the `sudo` option checked. Testing against my own on-premise GitLab, without passing a token and querying a group that I know has 70 projects in it, I can only see 3. Once I pass an token that has `sudo`, I can see all 70. It might be worth creating a new token so you can be sure you've checked sudo and try that.

Comment: yeha i pass tha token only and get the project and i have all access. in my command i give project means i get some of the project under group if give include suproups i get subgroup project only didnt get main project from group.

Comment: Adam Marshall is ther any problem with my command i didnget full project list

Comment: curl --silent --header "Private-Token: $token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/8523968/projects?include_subgroups=true&page=$page" | jq -r '.[] | [.id, .name, .web_url, .default_branch, .namespace.id] | @csv' >> result_branch.csv

Comment: Now that the curl command is working properly, the issue seems to be about permissions, depending on the token. Did you try creating a new token to ensure you have the `sudo` option checked?